# C++ code navigation on OS X

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm an OS X newbie. Other than setting up Emacs / Vim with ctags or cscope or both, are there alternatives to C++ code navigation of an existing code base? I used to use Source Insight on Windows and it worked for me fairly well. I know I can setup ctags or cscope but I was wondering if there is anything even better out there. The main functionality I am looking for is quickly find definition of variables and functions and places a function is being called.

Comment: have you tried stack overflow for this one?

Comment: @calavera, I was reluctant to post it on stackoverflow, but I did post on programmers and got one answer so far. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/22106/c-code-navigation-on-os-x

Comment: I was going to suggest that you take a look at Xcode and the developer tools. Xcode will allow you to Jump To Definition and project wide search. I believe you have found your answer elsewhere tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is Xcode not what you're looking for ? It's the Mac OS X IDE. It'sn't installed by default, but is present on your Mac OS X DVD.

Comment: Xcode might be just what I need. I have to wait and see. I tested ctags / cscope with vim as well and that could be enough as well.

Answer (score 1):

TextMate and BBEdit have significant followings.  I'm personally a big fan of Smultron even though development has stopped.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode:

> quickly find definition of variables
>   and functions

Right-click the variable name in question, and select "Jump to Definition".

Command (apple button) + double click on the variable is a shortcut for the same thing.

> quickly find places a function is
>   being called

Right-click the function name, and select "Find in Project" > "As Text".

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) for C++ programming on OS X.

Xcode will compile things but is not that good at dealing with C++ namespaces it is more of a C and Objectve-C tool